# How to get touch location latitude and longitude value from UIWebView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, webview, latitude-longitude

I'm working in iPhone application, Using `UIWebView` to load Google Map address and its works fine.
Then i tried to get the touch location `latitude` and `longitude` value from `UIWebView`, but i didn't know that, How to do this? Is it possible to do this? please help me

Thanks in Advance

I tried this:

```
    webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320,376)];
    webView.delegate=self;
    webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
    NSLog(@"URL:%@",[user valueForKey:@"google_Address"]);
    NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=37.785834,-122.406417&output=embed"];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: Use MapKit instead of webview to open Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution for your touch event coordinates but you will have to use MKmapView i am pasting the codes below

in .h

```
 #import <MapKit/MapKit.h> //import this in your project

 //define the objects;
 MKMapView *mapView;
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
```

**don't forget to add  MapKit.framework in your project**

in .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {

    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];//Release it in dealloc
    mapView.delegate=self;

    [self.view addSubview:mapView]; 
    [self displayRegion];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self      
    action:@selector(handleGesture:)];   
    tgr.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [mapView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
    [tgr release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
   }

    - (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
     {
         if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
          return;

         CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:mapView];
         coordinate = [mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView];

          NSLog(@"latitude  %f longitude %f",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude);


       }


       -(void)displayRegion
         {
           MKCoordinateRegion region;
           MKCoordinateSpan span;
           span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
           span.longitudeDelta=0.2;

           CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

           location.latitude = 22.569722 ;
           location.longitude = 88.369722;


            region.span=span;
            region.center=location;

            [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
            [mapView regionThatFits:region];
          }
```

i tested this code now its giving me correct values, and one more thing always try to test this on device not on simulator. Try and reply with your result i guess it should do the trick now

Comment: you can just make a fresh project and copy paste the above code to check its working or not then try implementing it in your original project you will come to know many things likewise.

Answer (score 0):

As per my above comment if you will use MapKit Then you can use the following code to get the lat/long of the touch location

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord= [MyMapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:MyMapView];
NSLog(@"latitude  %f longitude %f",coord.latitude,coord.longitude);


return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
```

}

Comment: Can u give any tutorial for this?

Comment: for using mapview/mapkit 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial
and http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/mapkit-example-in-iphone/
you can also google for more tutorials there are plenty available.

Comment: i have already see this tutorials but no one cannot tried my scenario, and also i tried your code in this tutorial but no help

Comment: then i guess you are missing some minor thing take in notice that my code will be true for mapview not webview;

Comment: can u please give your mail id, becozz i'll send my source code for this? please