# how to get latitude and longitude by view coordinates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am developing iPhone app and using google map. I used UIView for drawing region. Now I have implemented the touch event methods so how can i get longitude and latitude by view coordinates where user click on view??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449184/how-to-get-touch-location-latitude-and-longitude-value-from-uiwebview-in-iphone


it will give you idea.

Comment: Thanks but I am using google map for my application so the mehtod pointToCovert not working. So please provide me other alternative solution.

Comment: Use https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/examples/converting-points/

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question You need to create MKMapView that will give you the map property.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toCoordinateFromView:(UIView *)view`.

It converts the specified points to coordinates point.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D touchCoords = [self convertPoint:TOUCH_POINT toCoordinateFromView:YOUR_VIEW];
```